# Lazy Initialization and Templates - Linker error

Tags: templates, visual-c++, lazy-initialization, unresolved-external

I've a general problem with my application.
I want to use lazy initialization with an Array class I've made, to improve performances; all works fine when all code is in a single *.h file, but compiler returns a linker error when I split  the code in *.h*.cpp files.
In the header file I have a

```
template <class T>
class simpleArray { ... some methods\operators declarations. ... }
```

and

```
template <typename T, typename derType=simpleArray<T>>
class myArray{.... some methods\operators declarations. ... }
```

and I've the explicit declaration of:

```
template class myArray<double>; 
template class myArray<int>;
template class simpleArray<double>; 
template class simpleArray<int>;
```

In the *.cpp file I've the implementation of methods and operators.
Particularly I have two assignments operators:

```
template <class T, class derType>   
myArray<T,derType>& myArray<T,derType>::operator= (myArray<T,derType> const& right)
    {... some code ...}

template<class T, class derType>
template <class T2, class R2>   
    myArray<T,derType>& myArray<T,derType>::operator= (myArray<T2,R2> const& right) 
    { ... some code ...}
```

The first one works fine, the second one (Arra=Array) returns the following errors:

```
 Error  70  error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   
 Error  69  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class myArray <double,class simpleArray<double> > & __thiscall myArray <double,class simpleArray<double> >::operator=<int,class simpleArray<int> >(class myArray <int,class simpleArray<int> > const &)"
```

May you please suggest some solutions? Do I have to include all code in the same file?
I hope have been clear. Thank you for the support!

Ps. are there some "best practice" documents about code organization when using template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem raised because you've placed template `operator=` definition in `.cpp` file:

```
template <class T, class derType>
template <class T2, class R2>
myArray<T,derType>& myArray<T,derType>::operator=(myArray<T2,R2> const& right)
{ ... }
```

Explicit instantiation that you are using works fine with regular function members of template class, but it doesn't with template function members of template class.
Just because in explicit instatiation directive you provide only actual `T` and `derType` types which are class template parameters, but not `T2` and `R2` which are function template parameters.

Possible solutions:

1. Move template `operator=` definition to `.h`, so compiler will be able to instantiate it at the place of call
2. Provide explicit instantiations for template `operator=` with all possible combinations of `T`/`derType` and `T2`/`R2`:

Sample:

```
 // Explicit instantiation of template classes
 template class myArray<double>;
 template class myArray<int>;
 template class simpleArray<double>;
 template class simpleArray<int>; 

 // Explicit instantiation of template members
 template myArray<double>& myArray<double>::operator=(myArray<int> const&);
 template myArray<int>& myArray<int>::operator=(myArray<double> const&);
```

P.S. The best template guide is still [C++ Templates. The Complete Guide](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/) by David Vandevoorde and Nicolai M. Josuttis. It doesn't cover the new C++11 features yet, but the basics and most advanced topics are still actual.

Comment: Thank you for the answer: it's very clear! I was hoping there was a different way because with expression templates I've to instantiate all the combination of operators. Right? I will put all in a single *.h file.

Comment: Another question: if I want to export all code as a static library (a *.h and a *.lib file) how can I export templates and expression templates? Do I have to export all the *.h file? So the user will know the code and implementation... Or I can create another *.h file, related to the first one, with declarations only? Thank you!

Comment: @Dersu Yes. There is no way to export template except exporting its full definition. So you have to export all the header, right. Or export not the template itself but only some explicit instatiations. For expression templates it doesn't look possible as you have to instantiate all combinations and limit the number of operations in templated expression.

Comment: I've sent 2 positive feedback but I'm not able to give you a vote: there is a blocking pop-up; it needs 15 reputation and I have only 1. I'm sorry!

Comment: @Dersu Yes, but you can accept my answer - click on checkmark symbol near the top-left answer corner. This will give reputation both me and you.